# What is the most efficient way to create a DataFrame from two unrelated series?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm looking at creating a Dataframe that is the combination of two unrelated series.

If we take two dataframes:

```
A = ['a','b','c']
B = [1,2,3,4]

dfA = pd.DataFrame(A)
dfB = pd.DataFrame(B)
```

I'm looking for this output:

```
    A  B
0   a  1
1   a  2
2   a  3
3   a  4
4   b  1
5   b  2
6   b  3
7   b  4
8   c  1
9   c  2
10  c  3
11  c  4
```

One way could be to have loops on the lists direclty and create the DataFrame but there must be a better way. I'm sure I'm missing something from the pandas documentation.

```
result = []
for i in A:
    for j in B:
        result.append([i,j])

result_DF = pd.DataFrame(result,columns=['A','B'])
```

Ultimately I'm looking at combining months and UUID, I have something working but it takes ages to compute and relies too much on the index. A generic solution would clearly be better:

```
from datetime import datetime

start = datetime(year=2016,month=1,day=1)
end = datetime(year=2016,month=4,day=1)
months = pd.DatetimeIndex(start=start,end=end,freq="MS")
benefit = pd.DataFrame(index=months)

A = [UUID('d48259a6-80b5-43ca-906c-8405ab40f9a8'),
   UUID('873a65d7-582c-470e-88b6-0d02df078c04'),
   UUID('624c32a6-9998-49f4-92b6-70e712355073'),
   UUID('7207ab0c-3c7f-477e-b5bc-fbb8059c1dec')]
dfA = pd.DataFrame(A)

result = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','month'])
for i in dfA.index:
    newdf = pd.DataFrame(index=benefit.index)
    newdf['A'] = dfA.iloc[i,0]
    newdf['month'] = newdf.index
    result = pd.concat([result,newdf])
result
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `np.meshgrid`:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.array(np.meshgrid(dfA, dfB, )).T.reshape(-1, 2))

    0  1
0   a  1
1   a  2
2   a  3
3   a  4
4   b  1
5   b  2
6   b  3
7   b  4
8   c  1
9   c  2
10  c  3
11  c  4
```

to get a roughly `~2000x` speedup on `DataFrame` objects of length `300` and `400`, respectively:

```
A = ['a', 'b', 'c'] * 100
B = [1, 2, 3, 4] * 100

dfA = pd.DataFrame(A)
dfB = pd.DataFrame(B)
```

`np.meshgrid`:

```
%%timeit
pd.DataFrame(np.array(np.meshgrid(dfA, dfB, )).T.reshape(-1, 2))
100 loops, best of 3: 8.45 ms per loop
```

vs `cross`:

```
%timeit cross(dfA, dfB)
1 loop, best of 3: 16.3 s per loop
```

So if I understand your example correctly, you could:

```
A = ['a', 'b', 'c']
dfA = pd.DataFrame(A)

start = datetime(year=2016, month=1, day=1)
end = datetime(year=2016, month=4, day=1)
months = pd.DatetimeIndex(start=start, end=end, freq="MS")
dfB = pd.DataFrame(months.month)

pd.DataFrame(np.array(np.meshgrid(dfA, dfB, )).T.reshape(-1, 2))
```

to also get:

```
    0  1
0   a  1
1   a  2
2   a  3
3   a  4
4   b  1
5   b  2
6   b  3
7   b  4
8   c  1
9   c  2
10  c  3
11  c  4
```

Comment: Seems to be very fast but only to work on datatype that fit in an np array. If I try with a UUID i get 'TypeError: unsupported operand type(s)'

Comment: What `dtype` are you looking at?

Comment: See updated answer, let me know if I'm misunderstanding your example.

Comment: the `dtype` is `object` as I store values generated by `uuid.uuid4()`

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = ['a','b','c']
x,y = zip(*[i for i in zip(np.tile(a,len(a)),np.tile(b,len(a)))])
pd.DataFrame({'x':x,'y':y})
```

Outputs:

```
    x   y
0   1   a
1   2   b
2   3   c
3   1   a
4   2   b
5   3   c
6   1   a
7   2   b
8   3   c

%%timeit
1000 loops, best of 3: 559 µs per loop
```

---

EDIT: You don't actually need `np.tile`. A simple comprehension will do

```
x,y = zip(*[(i,j) for i in a for j in b])
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

result = pd.DataFrame(list(product(dfA.iloc[:,0], dfB.iloc[:,0])))
```

Not quite as efficient as `np.meshgrid`, but it's more efficient than the other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

One liner approach

```
pd.DataFrame(0, A, B).stack().index.to_series().apply(pd.Series).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Or:

```
pd.MultiIndex.from_product([A, B]).to_series().apply(pd.Series).reset_index(drop=True)
```

From dataframes, assuming the information is in the first column.

```
pd.MultiIndex.from_product([dfA.iloc[:, 0], dfB.iloc[:, 0]]).to_series().apply(pd.Series).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Functionalized:

```
def cross(df1, df2):
    s1 = df1.iloc[:, 0]
    s2 = df2.iloc[:, 0]
    midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([s1, s2])
    df = midx.to_series().apply(pd.Series).reset_index(drop=True)
    df.columns = [s1.name, s2.name if s1.name != s2.name else 1]
    return df

print cross(dfA, dfB)

    0  1
0   a  1
1   a  2
2   a  3
3   a  4
4   b  1
5   b  2
6   b  3
7   b  4
8   c  1
9   c  2
10  c  3
11  c  4
```

Comment: That's a nice one liner that I will store, but it still take the list and not a DataFrame as input, right?

Comment: Thanks ! Looking at the performance side of things on my simple example it looks like combining the dataframe is 10 times slower than using the loops and the list. I guess it's expected on such a small subject.